# why can't we use BillingAddress field in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

```
      why can't we use 
     <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingAddress" />  // using this throwing an error
```

Error: Data type not supported: Address    ..So I had to use below

```
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingStreet}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCity}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingState}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingCountry}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!account.BillingPostalCode}" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"BillingAddress" doesn't really exist. It appears only as a convenience when you're configuring page layouts. That same courtesy doesn't apply to Visualforce, which is much more literal. You can't bind to any complex field, such as "Name" on the Contact or Lead objects, etc.